# CL Editor - Syntax Highlighting - PHP

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, cleditor

I want to include PHP scripts in my website. I am using [CL editor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) to post contents. Can anyone help me to do syntax enabling in the CL editor.

Thanks

Comment: It does not look like that CL Editor offers a feature more or less close to what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

After you extract CLEditor in **protected/extensions/** this is the script to create it:

```
<?php $this->widget('Application.extensions.cleditor.ECLEditor',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                        'attribute'=>'isi',
                        'options'=>array(
                            'width'=>'700',
                            'height'=>250,
                            'useCSS'=>true,
                        ),
                        'value'=>$model->artikel
                    )); ?>
```

Try it :)